# Can "Pend" be used as a transitive verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I found myself writing a sentence as follows:

> I will pend the investigation for now.

Only to realise that I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to use pend as a verb in this sense. While not a logical basis, it "sounds" right.

I found online only mentions of it being used as an intransitive verb.[1](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pend)

See the following intransitive example:

> When your future is hinging upon the results of a courtroom trial,
> this is an example of a time when your future will pend on the trial.[2](https://www.yourdictionary.com/pend)

But I did not turn up any evidence of it being used as a transitive verb.

Regardless, I think that I would be understood by others if I used the word in this way. Only, it is not stated to be proper by the resources that I have found. Even so, does that render it incorrect?

Comment: What are you intending "I will pend the investigation for now" to mean?

Comment: The important part of the meaning of the verb "pend" is that the situation is awaiting some information, decision, or some other development. Without mentioning what that further development is, your sentence doesn't make much sense.  Maybe you could say, "I will pend the investigation until we have the coroner's report," but you need to mention the thing that you're *pending on* or *pending until*; not just the thing you're *pending*.

Comment: @GArthurBrown I intend it to mean that I will put the investigation on hold for now.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Sorry, the sentence was missing context. I isolated it because I thought it wasn't necessary. I was "pending the investigation" while awaiting a response from a colleague.

Comment: Wiktionary carries the transitive sense, easily found by searching for << pend + transitive >>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can :

> Transitive. To treat as pending; to postpone deciding on or attending to; **to defer**.

- 1953   P. Frankau Winged Horse iii. i. 178   Why didn't you ask J.G. to pend it **till New Year?**
- 1970   New Scientist 16 July 134   It has done this by ‘pending’ the settlement of nine patent applications.
- 2003   Westchester County (N.Y.) Business Jrnl. (Nexis) 17 Mar. 15   At times, claims are pended because of coordination of benefits or other issues, and **they may be delayed** somewhat.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/242383?rskey=pGLV0A&result=8#eid)

Comment: Thank you. I am accepting this answer because it provides evidence of usage. It does however deepen another line of thought that might be worth my asking in a separate question, namely as to why evidence provides assurance in language, which is constantly evolving and sees new words coming into use existence by _being_ used enough times that they are recognised.

Comment: Probably, in this case, 'pend' lacks usage as there are other words available : defer, delay, postpone, such that we are spoilt for choice, as is often the case in English where we borrow other words from other languages and which duplicate concepts.